# How many mails would cause this error to show in Gmail "There are too many messages on the other server. Please delete some mail from..."

Tags: email, gmail, pop3

I'm downloading my email to a private Gmail account, from another POP3 server (SmarterMail Server 4.3). In Gmail I'm getting the error:

```
Error: Too many messages to download.
Server returned error "There are too many messages on the other server. Please delete some mail from..."
```

So I can reduce the number of emails, but I don't know what maximum count I'm trying to hit.

Also using google on the error message only returns a few results from google sites, but non refer to an email count that would cause this error to start showing.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I've now systematically reduced the email in the Inbox folder of this server using it's webmail interface.

The magic number I needed to hit was **100,000 emails**. Having more than this amount of email on the server, caused the error in Gmail.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible for Gmail to only import new messages to avoid this error?

Comment: I can confirm this 100,000 limit as of today (6-24-23) as I just helped someone with this exact issue at just over 100K on the old/host POP3 server. He had "leave messages on server" checked in Gmail's POP3 retrieval options, so many messages were likely already downloaded, but it appears the initial POP3 check/compare stages (STAT/LIST commands) are limited to 100K by Google as I know of no inherent limit built into POP3 itself. Put differently, the limit is hit due to the *total* mail on the POP3 server (100K max), NOT solely the number of unread/undownloaded messages.